# I've found a way to use find -exec to cp multiple files all in one line like xargs, but I'm not sure exactly how it works

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find

I've been working with find -exec and find | xargs for the past few hours exploring and experimenting, and now I've found a variation of the command that I haven't seen anywhere else.

For example this find command to get all files in the child subdirectories and copy them to the current directory

```
find . -type f -regex './[^\.].*/[^.*].*' -exec sh -c 'cp "$@" .' thiscanbeanything {} +
```

will all execute on one line like so:

```
cp ./testy/bar ./testy/baz ./testy/foo .
```

Instead of the usual:

```
find . -type f -regex './[^\.].*/[^.*].*' -exec sh -c 'cp {} .' \;
```

which executes on multiple lines

```
cp ./testy/bar .
cp ./testy/baz .
cp ./testy/foo .
```

Moreover in the first command the output will be only:

```
cp ./testy/baz ./testy/foo .
```

Unless the `sh -c 'cmd'` is followed by something else, which in my example was `thiscanbeanything.`

Could someone elucidate what's going on, or if this is even viable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what is going on, have a look at this:

```
$ sh -c 'echo 0=$0 1=$1 2=$2' thiscanbeanything one two
0=thiscanbeanything 1=one 2=two
```

This executes `sh` with the option `-c 'echo 0=$0 1=$1 2=$2'` and three arguments `thiscanbeanything one two`.

Normally, `$0` is the name of the script being executed.  When running `sh -c`, there is no script but the name is taken from the first argument that your provide which, in this case, is `thiscanbeanything`.

#### Documentation

This behavior is documented in `man bash` under the `-c` option:

> -c string
>  If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.  If there are arguments  after  the  string, they are
>   assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

Comment: But then why does `thiscanbeanything` evaluate to `./testy/bar` which is the first file found by the find command?

Comment: @AR7 Because `"$@"` does not include `$0`.  Instead, it evaluates, as it always does, to `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...`.  Because you are not using `$0` for anything, it really can be anything.

Comment: So normally `./testy/bar` is getting assigned to `$0`, but by providing an argument `anything` after `sh -c` the argument `anything` gets assigned to `$0` instead, meaning that `./testy/bar` gets assigned to `$1`. Did I get that right?

Comment: @AR7 Yes. The `anything` is added so that the arguments you want are assigned to their normal positions in `"$@"`.